# gtm-oauth2 access to own server configuration

Tags: ios, symfony, callback, oauth-2.0, selector

SHORT STORY

Using gtm-oauth2 for iOS and FOSOAuthServerBundle in Symfony2 to implement my own Oauth2 server I am not getting the callBack `finishedSelector` to be invoked.

This is where the "special" ViewController is created:

```
    GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch * viewController;
viewController = [[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch alloc] initWithAuthentication:myAuth
                                                             authorizationURL:authURL
                                                             keychainItemName:nil
                                                                     delegate:self
                                                             finishedSelector:@selector(viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:)];
```

What are the reasons that might make finishedSelector, (the implemented method `viewController:finishedWithAuth:error`) not to be invoked?

The behavior I get is that the login page is properly rendered, but it acts as the starting point of the whole web application, rendering the rest of the pages once it is logged-in instead of returning the control to the finishedSelector and, finally, to the view controller that has to manage the continuation of the APP workflow.

LONG STORY

Using gtm-oauth2 and FOSOAuthServerBundle in Symfony2, I am experiencing problems trying to make the arquitecture to catch the login and load the authenticated session from my iOS APP.

I am following the instructions described in the [gtm-oauth2 documentation](http://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth2/wiki/Introduction#Using_the_OAuth_2_Controllers), particularly the [Signing in to non-Google Services](http://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth2/wiki/Introduction#Signing_in_to_non-Google_Services) part.

Doing what it is described there, I have this method for creating the `auth` object:

```
- (GTMOAuth2Authentication * ) authForMyAPP
{
    //This URL is defined by the individual 3rd party APIs, be sure to read their documentation
    NSString * url_string = @"http://myHost/oauth/v2/token";
    NSURL * tokenURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url_string];
    // We'll make up an arbitrary redirectURI.  The controller will watch for
    // the server to redirect the web view to this URI, but this URI will not be
    // loaded, so it need not be for any actual web page. This needs to match the URI set as the
    // redirect URI when configuring the app.
    NSString * redirectURI = @"http://myHost/oauth/v2/falseCallBack";
    GTMOAuth2Authentication * myAuth;
    myAuth = [GTMOAuth2Authentication authenticationWithServiceProvider:@"MyAPP"
                                                               tokenURL:tokenURL
                                                            redirectURI:redirectURI
                                                               clientID:kMyClientID
                                                           clientSecret:kMyClientSecret
              ];
    //[myAuth setTokenType:@"Bearer"];
    return myAuth;
}
```

And then, this method creates the "special" viewController that should handle the render of the login page and returning the control when the login is performed:

```
- (void)signInToMyAPP()
{
    GTMOAuth2Authentication *myAuth = [self authForMyAPP];
    NSString* auth_string = @"http://127.0.0.1/~pgbonino/Symfony/web/app.php/oauth/v2/auth";
    NSURL * authURL = [NSURL URLWithString:auth_string];
    // Display the authentication view

    // Creates the "special" viewController passing the `auth` object, the authorization URL and the finishedSelector
    GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch * viewController;
    viewController = [[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch alloc] initWithAuthentication:myAuth
                                                             authorizationURL:authURL
                                                             keychainItemName:nil
                                                                     delegate:self
                                            finishedSelector:@selector(viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:)];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}
```

Finally, I have the method used for that finishedSelector. It should be called once the login is properly performed and the authentication has succeeded (or an error has come). THAT IS WHAT I AM NOT GET DONE:

```
- (void)viewController:(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *)viewController
  finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)myAuth
             error:(NSError *)error
{
    if (error != nil)
    {
        // Authentication failed
        UIAlertView *alertView = [ [UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Authorization Failed"
                                                         message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                        delegate:self
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss"
                                               otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
    else
    {
        // Authentication succeeded

        // Assign the access token to the instance property for later use
        //self.accessToken = myAuth.accessToken;
        [myAuth setShouldAuthorizeAllRequests:YES];
        [[Singleton sharedSingleton] setAuth:myAuth];

        // Display the access token to the user
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Authorization Succeeded"
                                                        message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Access Token: %@", myAuth.accessToken]
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
}
```

This all is supposed to render my login page in a web view and catch the successful login to call the `viewController:finishedWithAuth:error` and save the session in some shared object.

Nevertheless, the behavior I am getting is that I get rendered the login in the web view, I correctly login and, instead oF the delegated selector gets invoked, it just normally logs in the application and the next page is loaded in the web view, as if it was in a normal browser. So the callback is not performed.

Why am I not getting the selector to be called? Any idea?

IMPORTANT NOTE: the Oauth2 server works perfectly: if I call the token URL and the callBack url from Safari, everything works well. Tokens and auths codes are correctly saved in database.

Answer (score 0):

Forget it.

It was just me.

OAuth2 won't work with Symfony2 and FOSUserBundle while this parameter is set to true in `config.yml`:

```
always_use_default_target_path: false
```